# segue storyboard condition issue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, storyboard

I have this two controller liked by segue:

[image]

My problem is that:

when I tap on selected table view'cell in general I have to follow the segue and so go to other controller , but if a specific condition is true I have to show ad alert view and so I don't follow the segue and so don't go to those controller.

In this way when I tap on selected cell I go always on the other controller.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: what do you mean by "tap on selected table view cell"? Do you want to say "when you tap on a cell"?

Answer (score 1):

if you override this function segue wont continue if you return false, this gives you the oportunity to show a warning under certain conditions, after that you can performSegueWithIdentifier("segueidentifier", sender: self), and your good to go.

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String!, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {

    if identifier == "segueidentifier" {
        //show warning and perform segue with this identifier on the accept button listener.
        return false 
    }
}
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a segue from one controller to another without specifying exact view which triggers the segue. Then just check your condition in `didSelectRow` method and call `performSegue` method if you need to show new view controller:

```
if condition {
   performSegue(withIdentifier: "MySegueIdentifier", sender: nil)
}
else {
   //show ad here
}
```

To add a segue between controllers just drag with right mouse button from one controller to another and pick "Show".

[image]

Then select segue and add a string identifier for it:

[image]

Make sure you use the same string in the code when you call `performSegue` method.

Comment: I don't understand : when condition is not true I have not to go to specific controller but I show only alert view. How do I link segue from table view ' cell to not a controller.Can you explain better? thank you so much for your time

Comment: Update the answer. Feel free to ask questions if any.