# Change variable and send it to second view controller

Tags: ios, swift, function, uiviewcontroller

I am creating a shop screen for my game. Where you can buy character for example. I need a variable to change when a button is pressed on the shop view and then for it to be sent to the next view controller. The second view controller will then select the correct player based on the value of the variable i have the following code for the shop view controller:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Shop: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject){
        var x = 1
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "segue") {
            let dest = segue.destination as! GameViewController
            dest.x = x
        }
    }
}
```

But the variable is not global so how do i do it. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirements I believe a global Singleton object is your best option.

A global singleton will allow you to access your shop data across controllers.

E.g.

```
class ShopManager {
    static let sharedInstance = ShopManager()

    var x = 0 // some initial value

    private init() {} //Ensures singleton is unique
}
```

Now you can get/set `ShopManager.sharedInstance.x` (or any other variables/objects declared in the singleton class) anywhere without having to pass data between controllers.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Shop: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject){
        ShopManager.sharedInstance.x = 1
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "segue") {
            let dest = segue.destination as! GameViewController
            //no need to set dest.x here. just access ShopManager.sharedInstance.x from the destination controller!
        }
    }
}

class ShopManager {
    static let sharedInstance = ShopManager()

    var x = 0 // some initial value

    private init() {} //Ensures singleton is unique
}
```

Comment: Note that with this approach there is no need in `prepare for segue` method at all (assuming you don't need to pass anything else)

Comment: Hold on how do i access the variables in the other views

Comment: @ArthurMacpherson Just used `ShopManager.sharedInstance.x`. You need to remove `static` keyword before `var x`, since it should be an instance variable

Comment: hmm I didn't need to change any of the above code in order to access the variables in any view/class in my project. `ShopManager.x` should be accessible from any class/view

Comment: @Danoram: Yes, you can, but should you? What's the point of singleton `sharedInstance` if you use static variables?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can store `x` as a variable in `ShopViewController`:

```
var x: Int?

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject){
    x = 1
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "segueId") {
        let dest = segue.destination as! GameViewController
        dest.x = x
    }
}
```

2. You can [add a segue from one controller to another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40137869/1689376) instead of an exact button and perform it from your callback:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject){
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueId", sender: 1)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "segueId") {
        let dest = segue.destination as! GameViewController
        dest.x = sender as! Int
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, singleton makes sense in your case. But if that value is not going to be used anywhere except these two controllers, it may be a better choice not to expose it globally. So it depends, which approach is more appropriate in a particular situation.